# Automatically commenting on closed Github issues

Tags: github, workflow

Closing issues by adding `Fix #120` to commit messages and PRs is an
extremely useful feature, in principle.
In practice, however, I commonly end up visiting the issue anyway and adding a comment like:
*“Could you confirm whether this solved the problem for you?”*

**I would like to have a comment such as that added automatically to
an issue, whenever it is closed from a commit message or PR message.**

Is there a service that provides this feature? I understand Github
supports hooks that are triggered on every push, so I known it's
possible in principle. But I've never used them before, so I don't
know how to write one.

Comment: I don't think that it's a good idea to automate communication with *people*—if I was your user, I'd not like the idea of speaking with a bot.

Comment: @lunaryorn true. I would only use a solution to this if the comment is posted from my account, but I didn't want to be picky in my question as I felt I was already asking for much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Github channel on ifttt.com:

https://ifttt.com/github

Comment: According to that link, there's a "Closed issues" channel, but its ingredients don't say how it was closed. So maybe if this was passed to a script that contacted the github api and checked how it was closed.